# Why is my UIGestureRecognizer Swipe not working? Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Here's my GameViewController.m file:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewLoad];
        .
        .
        .
        _board = [[TwinstonesBoardModel alloc] init];
        [_board setToInitialStateMain];
        TwinstonesStoneView* twinstonesBoard = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc]
                                          initWithMainFrame:CGRectMake(12, 160, 301.5, 302.5)
                                          andBoard:_board];
        [self.view addSubview:twinstonesBoard];

        TwinstonesStonesView *stoneOne = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc] init];
        TwinstonesStonesView *one = (TwinstonesStoneView*)stoneOne.stoneUnoView;
        TwinstonesStonesView *stoneTwo = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc] init];
        TwinstonesStonesView *two = (TwinstonesStoneView*)stoneTwo.stoneDueView;

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self
                                             action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        [one addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
        [two addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

Here's the relevant code in my TwinstonesStoneView.m file:

```
    @implementation TwinstonesStoneView
    {
        NSMutableArray* _array;
        NSMutableArray* _emptyArray;
        CGRect _frame;
        NSUInteger _column;
        NSUInteger _row;
        TwinstonesBoardModel* _board;

        int _i;
    }

    - (id)initWithMainFrame:(CGRect)frame andBoard:
                                       (TwinstonesBoardModel*)board
    {
      if (Self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
      {
        float rowHeight = 49.0;
        float columnWidth = 49.0;
        float barrierHorizontalRowHeight = 12.5;
        float barrierVerticalColumnWidth = 12.5;

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) 
        {
          for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
          {
            TwinstonesStonesView* square = [[TwinstonesStoneView alloc]
                 initWithEmptyFrame:CGRectFrame(//spacial equations, not important)
                 column:col
                 row:row
                 board:board];

            BoardCellState state = [board cellStateAtColumn:col andRow:row];

            if (state == BoardCellStateStoneOne) {
                // _stoneUnoView is a public property
                // 'stoneOneCreation' creates a UIImageView of the stone
                _stoneUnoView = [UIImageView stoneOneCreation];
                [self addSubview:square];
                [square addSubview:_stoneUnoView];
                [_array insertObject:_stoneUnoView atIndex:0];
            } else if (state == BoardCellStateStoneTwo) {
                // same idea as above
                _stoneDueView = [UIImageView stoneTwoCreation];
                [self addSubview:square];
                [square addSubview:_stoneDueView];
                [_array insertObject:_stoneDueView atIndex:1];
            } else {
                // based on the 'init' method I write below, I assumed this
                // would return an empty square cell
                [self addSubview:square];
                [_emptyArray insertObject:square atIndex:_i];
                _i++;
            }
          }
        }
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      }
      return self;
    }

    - (UIView*)stoneUnoView {
        return _stoneUnoView;
    }

    - (UIView*)stoneDueView {
        return _stoneDueView;
    }

    - (id)initWithEmptyFrame:(CGRect)frame
                      column:(NSUInteger)column
                         row:(NSUInteger)row
                       board:(TwinstonesBoardModel*)board
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        return self;
    }

    - (void)swipeLeft:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
        NSLog(@"Swipe Left");
        UIView* view = recognizer.view;
        [self move:CGPointMake(-1, 0) withView:view];
    }

    - (void)move:(CGPoint)direction withView:view {
        // whatever code I decide to put for stone movement
    }

    @end
```

I apologize for the (probably) unnecessary length, I've just trying to figure this out for a couple days and have had no luck.  Here's the bullet points of what I'm trying to do:
        1.  setInititalStateMain sets the placements of two stones in a 5x5 grid
        2.  In GameViewController.m, I'm trying to capture the 'stoneUnoView' and 
'stoneDueView' properties (set in the TwinstonesStoneView.m file), give them swipe gestures, and interact with them using the methods provided in TwinstonesStoneView.m.
        3.  Am I generating too many views?  The catch is that everything works in terms of what I'm able to see on my IPhone when I run the program.  The stones show up on my screen, but when I try to interact with them, not even the 'NSLog' message shows up in the console.
        4.  The 'stoneOneCreation' method (and ...two) are UIImageView's, but, as you can see, I store them in a UIView pointer.
        5.  I also used '[one setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]' (and ...two) but that didn't help either.
        6.  If I add the gesture recognizer to self.view, everything works (the displays of the stones, gameboard, and other graphics appears, and when I interact with ANY part of the screen, I output the directions to the console......just not stone-specific interaction).

Thank you so very much for putting up with all of this, this will really help if someone knows what's wrong.  PS: all file #import's are correct, so that isn't a problem.

I am using XCode 7, Objective-C language, and developing for iOS

- Anthony

Answer (score 0):

One thing that catches my eye is I don't think you can add the same gesture recognizer to multiple views.  I suspect, at best, only the last view is actually receiving it.

Comment: I commented out one of the views to try it out and it still didn't work.  I always thought you could give the same gesture to multiple views seeing as the views themselves are separate entities.  Thanks

Comment: I'm still pretty sure you can't reuse gestures, but you seem to have removed that as a possible issue.  Do you have user interaction enabled on those views?  If it's off, then I believe the gestures won't trigger.

Comment: Yea, I have that line [one setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; on and off.   'one' being a TwinstonesStoneView (subclass of UIView), so I don't know why that line would even matter.

Comment: Ahh, I see that in your description.  My bad!  My last thought then, is there another gesture that is stealing your swipe gesture?  Depending on your view hierarchy, your swipes might be getting intercepted by another view's gesture recognizer.

Comment: Wait, you mentioned UIImageView...  Do THEY have user interaction turned on?  Even if a child view has it turned on, it is still off if it's super view has it turned off (and UIImageView has it off by default).

Comment: How do you mean?  To fill you in, I have 3 other methods for the other 3 directions as swipe gestures (also added to the 'one' and 'two' views).  But I commented them all out, so what I have left is 'one' with a left swipe gesture...that's it.  Still not working.   Do I just have too many instances and references?  I mean, I followed the connection paths around (drew it out on paper keeping track of all my instances) and theoretically it all makes sense.

Comment: No, this might be the issue!  How do I do that?  I have a separate 'Stone Creation' file for +(instancetype) methods.  Nowhere in that file is a 'set user interaction enabled'.  When I follow my reference paths around, obviously it gets to that file to call the 'stoneOneCreation' (...and two) method....which is a result of a UIImageView:UIView instance variable creation (essentially the originator of all the references).    How would I enable that interaction?

Comment: I admit to not reading the sample code in great detail, but does it make sense to simply add _stoneUnoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES in your code snippet (same for Due)?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work...I actually put that line (Sort of like NSLog caveman debugging) in every part of the code that has a UIView reference for that case but nothing seems to work.  Is there such a thing as subviews upon subviews for which user interaction can't occur?  Like, is my 'stone' view not able to receive any touches because it's not the foremost view, or hidden beneath other views?

Comment: Also, although I don't see this to be an issue, I don't actually have any outlet connections for these files.  I'm just doing it all programmatically.  That shouldn't be an issue correct?  I don't ALSO have to attach a UISwipeGesture connection to a storyboard view do I?  Just coding it should work...?

Answer (score 0):

try this but i am not sure try this, just create 2 swipe gestures
in `GameViewController.m`

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewLoad];
    //.... other code
    //comment below line 
   // UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     //initWithTarget:self //setting self is the problem is the problem
                                     //action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                initWithTarget:stoneOne //set target will be one
                                     action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

    [one addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeLeft_2 = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                             initWithTarget:stoneTwo //this will be two
                             action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

    [two addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft_2]; //set the gesture
 }
```

u are setting the gesture to `self` which means the actions are sent to `GameViewController.m` but we want actions to be in `TwinstonesStoneView.m` so change the target to view to `TwinstonesStoneView`. And also if it is image views u are adding gestures, then enable user interaction for each image views `setUserInteractionEnabled:`

just try it